# Sending HTTP requests with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, http, reactjs

I have a questing related to ReactJS and hope you guys can help me out with this. This question has few sections.

[Sample diagram of the project architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLv52.jpg)

As you can see in the attached image, I’m trying to create a UI with respect to the response I’m getting from the server.

1st I have a **BASE** component. From that component, I’m sending a GET request to the server to get the response to create **LEVEL 2 COMPONENTS**. In the architecture, which I’m using in the application, I have modularized all the components. So, I have only **1** LEVEL 2 UI COMPONENT designed. **Depending on the response from the server, it will automatically regenerate how many LEVEL 2 COMPONENTS needs to be generated in the BASE component**.

As per this examples, I have 2 LEVEL 2 COMPONENTS with component ids as **“COMP_001”** and **“COMP_002”**. With that response from the server, I can dynamically create 2 UI components on the BASE component.

Then I need to send another 2 GET requests from each LEVEL 2 COMPONENTS with their respective IDs to get the response to create LEVEL 3 COMPONENTS. this is where I’m struggling with. When I bind the IDs which I’m getting from the previous response as a property (this.props.component_id), it will get only the 1st component id and send the request using that. So, both LEVEL 3 COMPONENTS have the same data. I want to get different data to both LEVEL 3 components by sending GET requests using COMP_001 and COMP_002 IDs.

Please tell me how to resolve this issue.
Thank you in advance.

BASE COMPONENT

```
var BASE = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {baseData: []};
    },
    componentWillMount: function () {
        HTTPService.get('/get/base/component/data')
            .then(function (arrayData) {
                this.setState({baseData: arrayData.data});
            }.bind(this));
    },

    render: function () {
        var baseDataFunc = this.state.baseData.map(function (item) {
            return <LEVEL2COMPONENT L2COMPID={item._id} L2COMPNAME={item.comp_name}/>
        });
        return (
            <div>
                {baseDataFunc}
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

LEVEL 2 COMPONENT

```
var LEVEL2COMPONENT = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {level2data: []};
    },
    componentWillMount: function () {
        HTTPService.get('/get/level2/component/data/'+this.props.L2COMPID+'/with/this/id')
            .then(function (arrayData) {
                this.setState({level2data: arrayData.data});
            }.bind(this));
    },

    render: function () {
        var level2DataFunc = this.state.level2data.map(function (item) {
            return <LEVEL3COMPONENT L3COMPID={item._id} L3COMPNAME={item.comp_name}/>
        });
        return (
            <div>
                {level2DataFunc}
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

Comment: You have a missing `'` inside your level 2 component's `componentWillMount()` method.

Comment: @Raymond Thank you for noticing that, but that is not the issue which i'm having right now? that was just a typo occurred when I was posting this question.

Comment: Pretty weird. I tried the same architecture and everything works fine -- when request level-3-component data, different level-2-component ID is passed, then different level-3-component data is retrieved.

Comment: BTW, you missed the unique `key` prop for array structure.